# How can I add upload file formats in my code

Tags: php

I have a problem. This code can upload only images and I need to upload other file types too.
How can I add file upload types/formats and how to add file upload size limit?
Please help me to solve this problem.

```
<?
if (!empty($_FILES['uploaded_file'])) {
    $path = "uploads/";
    $path = $path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
        echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']). 
            " has been uploaded";
    } else{
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Hello, in the code given nothing is restricted to only images

Comment: Could you add also the HTML form? I think it is restricted in the form, your PHP code does not do any restrictions.